# setSupportActionBar toolbar cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar) error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, toolbar

I've been looking for an answer and I've tried many possible solutions, but nothing seems to work..

I'm trying to setup a Material Action Bar following [this tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html).

Here's my code:

**tool_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#1C1C1C"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**And finally my activity.java:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


public class rutaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ruta);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();//Ocultar ActivityBar anterior

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //HERE'S THE PROBLEM !!!!
```

**Error:**

> setSupporActionBar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) in ActionBarActivity cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In your `Activity.java` import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class rutaActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ruta);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();//Ocultar ActivityBar anterior

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //NO PROBLEM !!!!
```

**Update:**

If you are using [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), replace

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

with newer imports

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` as Google has depreciated it.

Comment: when i use toolbar in android class extens actionbaractivity setsupportActionBar(tool) showing error setsupport toolbar v7 appdelegar error please help me

Answer (score 23):

In using toolbar you should extends AppCompatActivity and

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: Extends `AppCompatActivity` gave me the clue I was missing.

Answer (score 19):

For adding a ToolBar that supports Material Design, the [official documentation directions](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar) are probably the best to follow.

1. Add the [v7 appcompat support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat).
2. Make your activity extend `AppCompatActivity`.

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     // ...
   }
   ```
3. Declare `NoActionBar` in the Manifest.

   ```
   <application
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
       />
   ```
4. Add a toolbar to your activity's xml layout.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
      ...
      />
   ```
5. Call `setSupportActionBar` in the activity's `onCreate`.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
       Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
   }
   ```

**Note:** You will have to import the following in the activity.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: Forgot to extend AppCompatActivity and was getting an Unresolved Reference on setSupportActionBar. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena stop spamming other people's answers with a link to another answer.

Answer (score 8):

**For Android version above 3:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

**For Android version below 3:**

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 5):

With the addition of androidx in Studio 3.0+ the Toolbar compatibility is now in a new library, accessible like this

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 2):

Certify that your Manifest declaration includes **android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"** tag, like the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".PointsScreen"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar to the import list resolve this issue.

Then add the toolbar widget layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/list_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    />
```

In onCreate method of java code

```
//call to
```

Tootbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action

Comment: This will not help.

Comment: It tried it and it works for me. take note of the import statement import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and the toolbar <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

class must be extend of AppCompatActivity to resolve the problem of setSuppertActionBar that is not recognizable

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

To

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

ToolBar's name can easily be changed using

```
android:label="My Activity"
```

in your Manifest File.
I just going through Manifest & found

```
android:label
```

Helps to change according to the specific activity, Hope you'll give it a try

Comment: It's most sophisticated way I've ever found, did it helped to u ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using previously this code:

```
Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and extended AppCompatActivity also but I was getting the same error.
So in place of using **Toolbar** class, I have imported the below class and it worked for me:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

import it into your java class

Answer (score -2):

In You MainActivity.java import android .support.v7.widget.Toolbar  insert of java program