# Android Studio Showing "Cannot Resolve Symbol" after Updating to API Level 22

Tags: android, android-studio

Okay, so today I updated my SDK tools to level 22 (Yup, this late). Before I was on level 21 and wrote an app. Now after updating to level 22, I want to use `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` API.

The problem is that when I import `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`, Android Studio shows error saying "cannot resolve symbol". I used the search and found that there did exist a `CardView` class in the `android.support.v7.widget` package.

Moreover, in the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` API, I can't use some of the newer methods added like the `setActionbar()` method.

I also can't seem to import the `AppCompatActivity` class.

I have updated the Target API to level 22.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: com.android.support:cardview-v7

Comment: Thanks... It worked. Any solution for the Toolbar's setActionBar() method not showing

Comment: If you use AppCompat library, please use `setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar)` with whatever style coming from `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025961/setsupportactionbar-toolbar-error

Comment: Worked it out... I had already added appcompat to the dependency list, but due to some bug, it didn't show up. Added it to the dependency list again and used the setSupportActionbar() method instead