# How to resolve the Android error "method setSupportActionBar in class AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to given types"?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm making an Android app using `appcompat` using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3` and getting following error.

> Error:(22, 9)  error: method setSupportActionBar in class
>   AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar found: android.widget.Toolbar 
>   reason: actual argument android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar by method invocation conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all appcompat **23.0.3 doesn't exist**.

Use **23.0.1**

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
```

Then the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)) `setSupportActionBar` works with `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Check the **import in your code**.
When you are using the `Toolbar`,you have to use the right import:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Finally also in **your layout**, you have to use the right widget.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ..... />
```

Answer (score 3):

I have problem same with you

I change `extends Activity` to `extends ActionBarActivity`

Like this:

```
public class myclass extends Activity
```

to

```
public class myclass extends ActionBarActivity
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `android.widget.Toolbar` import statement to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget ToolBar
New solution to change Name of Activities is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56591350/10505463)
Use Manifests &

```
android:label="name_to_be_changed"
```

for ex.

```
`<enter code hereactivity android:name=".MyActivity"
android:label="My Activity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>`
```

Comment: long time no replies, Is that helpful or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while adding toolbar widget. In my case, I have changed import link to : 
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

just 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,
and make sure that your xml file tool bar contain same like this 
after that extend the class AppCompatActivity 
i think this solve your problem