# Toolbar empty with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

My `BaseDrawerActivity` extends `BaseActivity` and I have a `Toolbar` in `BaseActivity`.

The toolbar shows with no issues in classes that extend `BaseActivity`, but ALL classes that extend `BaseDrawerActivity` just show a blank toolbar. The nav drawer works fine.

When I had one main activity class (BaseActivity + BaseDrawerActivity) the toolbar showed no problem and the nav drawer worked.

**Why is my implementation here not showing the `Toolbar`? I debugged and getToolbar() is returning the toolbar for sure.**

**activity_base_drawer.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <include layout="@layout/call_to_action_banner"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            style="@style/NavDrawerListView" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarOverlay"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

**BaseDrawerActivity**

```
public abstract class BaseDrawerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final int LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.activity_base_drawer;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private NavDrawerAdapter mNavDrawerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT_ID);

        setupNavDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void setupNavDrawer() {
        final ListView navDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_header, null, false);
        mNavDrawerAvatarImageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        mNavDrawerUsernameTextView = (CustomTextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
        navDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                getToolbar(),
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                updateNavDrawerUserInfo();
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mNavDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this);
        navDrawerListView.setAdapter(mNavDrawerAdapter);
        navDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
            }
        });

        updateNavDrawerUserInfo();
    }

    private void updateNavDrawerUserInfo() {
        final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
        if (db.doesUserExist(SharedPrefs.getUserId())) {
            final User currentUser = db.getUser(SharedPrefs.getUserId());

            if (currentUser != null) {
                if (currentUser.getAvatarType() != null) {
                    try {
                        mNavDrawerAvatarImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                ViewUtil.getAvatarHeadDrawableId(this,
                                        currentUser.getAvatarType())));
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (currentUser.getUsername() != null) {
                    mNavDrawerUsernameTextView.setText(currentUser.getUsername());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity**

```
private void setupToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo_toolbar);
    }

    mUpdatingSpinner = (ProgressBar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.toolbar_updating_spinner, null, false);
    int dpInPixels = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_updating_spinner);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams spinnerLp = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(dpInPixels, dpInPixels,
            Gravity.END);
    mToolbar.addView(mUpdatingSpinner, spinnerLp);
}
```

Comment: Please show the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `styles.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer although I don't fully understand it.

I basically called `setupToolbar()` again in my `BaseDrawerActivity` right before I call `setupNavDrawer()` and for some reason this fixed it.

I think the reference to the `Toolbar` from `BaseActivity` wasn't retrieving correctly (even though I debugged and it had a reference to it). Another thing I tried is `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` right before setting up the nav drawer but that didn't work.

If anyone has any ideas as to why I have to setup the toolbar again in order for it to show I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: Android developer core team, please come in on this one. Many are striving to get the Toolbar replacing the ActionBar, the problem often being that the ToolBar is empty. It is there, but empty. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar).`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025961/setsupportactionbar-toolbar-error) should help.

Comment: I do `setSupportActionBar` in my `BaseActivity`. Edited my post to include the code of my `Toolbar` setup method. Remember that the toolbar works in classes that extend `BaseActivity`. It's just the `BaseDrawerActivity`s.

Comment: Have you made sure that everything eventually inherits from ActionBarActivity

Comment: Yes, my BaseActivity extends from `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and replace

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

with

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: My `AppTheme` style is: <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">. And it works fine with my BaseActivity... Pretty sure it is not a theme issue.