# How should I import Toolbar tool in android studio?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, material-components-android

I am trying to add a `Toolbar` to my android studio project. I found several explanations of how should I do it and they all explained [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302444/11222417). In the first step, I should import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` but it does not succeed: The `v7` characters bulbing in red and the warning message is: "Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'". I tried to replace the `v7` with `v4` which is included in the suggestions bar after the `import android.support.____` but when I do so, the android studio claims it "cannot resolve symbol 'widget'".

How can I import the `Toolbar` tool successfully?

Comment: Are you using androidx libraries?

Comment: I am not sure. the fields `android.useAndroidX` and  `android.enableJetifier` in `gradle.properties` are set to `true` so I guess I do.

Comment: Are you using `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:x.x.x'` or `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Androidx libraries you have to:

- use the right class in your code `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.
- use the right AppCompativity: `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`
- use `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in your layout

If you want to use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

- add the library `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'`
- follow the [getting started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) page to change the theme to a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme
- Use the `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` in your code and in your layout