# Can't use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar; gives an error  "Cannot resolve symbol v7" , i tried implementation in gradle but didn't work , please help

i will provide images and code bellow

[TOOLBAR XML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6aHr.png)

[SOCIAL MEADIA CLASS XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhRy6.png)

[SOCIAL MEDIA JAVA CLASS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQidB.png)

[GRADLE DEPENDENCIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Itox.png)

**dependencies** {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"
implementation 'com.github.Shashank02051997:FancyToast-Android:0.1.6'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**XML CODE**

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

**JAVA CLASS**

public class SocialMediaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private TabAdapter tabAdapter;

public SocialMediaActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_media);
}
```

}

Comment: use should use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: Check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286604/how-should-i-import-toolbar-tool-in-android-studio/58286815#58286815)

Answer (score 5):

The v7 support library does not appear in your dependencies in your gradle file.  The v7 support library has been deprecated.  You should use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.  See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx.  You have the dependency `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` in your gradle file, so you'll have access to the androidx toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is there any way so I can use the v7 support library?

Comment: Try the dependency `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`.

Comment: Gradle gives me this error "Version 28 (intended for android Pie and bellow) is the last version of the legacy support library"

Comment: Ok. You'll have to switch to the AndroidX Toolbar or target a lower SDK with your build.

Answer (score 1):

While using androidX you need to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` for toolbar. And add `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` to app level gradle file.