# MainActivity@2325a0d does not have an ActionBar set via setSupportActionBar() When use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I'm trying to remove ActionBar so I added @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to my manifest. But it wasn't work.

I also tried to add codes like

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

But it wasn't work too

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yeonfish.bigbrother, PID: 6127
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yeonfish.bigbrother/com.yeonfish.bigbrother.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.yeonfish.bigbrother.MainActivity@2325a0d does not have an ActionBar set via setSupportActionBar()
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setSupportActionBar toolbar cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025961/setsupportactionbar-toolbar-cannot-be-applied-to-android-widget-toolbar-error)

Comment: Please edit your question and show the manifest entry for MainActivity and also the code for `MainActivity.onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getSupportActionBar().hide();`.

Comment: If the exception says **"Activity X does not have an ActionBar set via `setSupportActionBar()`** what makes you think that `getSupportActionBar()` wouldn't throw the same exception?

Comment: @DavidWasser But.. the problem solved by his solution

Answer (score 0):

just check if you are using this block of code, it makes the problem.
I removed it and that solved the problem.

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
```